# Launching Google Chrome takes me to MSN homepage

Tags: google-chrome

I've installed Google Chrome on Windows XP, but when I open it I'm taken to MSN homepage.
Is this normal?

Comment: Isn't that the default home page for Internet Explorer? If you've imported your browser settings, that's exactly what I would expect to happen.

Comment: Its normal if you imported those settings over from a different browser.  Why don't you just change it.  Its not like the MSN homepage is malicious.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments imply, Chrome imports everything (settings, history, homepage, etc.) from your "default browser" automatically during the installation. Maybe, you're using IE as your default browser and haven't changed the homepage yet  :-)

So, there's no need to worry about the homepage. Just change it to whatever you wish...

**Note:** Though I really had `msn.com` as my default homepage in IE-7, Chrome showed the homepage as `google.com` because I use firefox which stays with Google as homepage.